# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified when using export_graphviz

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-visualization, random-forest

I trained my model using Random Forest and I want to Visualize the Decision Tree. Then, I want to convert the export_graphviz to a png file.

```
from subprocess import call

# Convert to png
call(['dot', '-Tpng', 'tree_from_optimized_forest.dot', '-o', 'tree_from_optimized_forest.png', '-Gdpi=200'])
Image('tree_from_optimized_forest.png')
```

The output is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-f836aa32a65b> in <module>
      2 
      3 # Convert to png
----> 4 call(['dot', '-Tpng', 'tree_from_optimized_forest.dot', '-o', 'tree_from_optimized_forest.png', '-Gdpi=200'])
      5 Image('tree_from_optimized_forest.png')

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in call(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    321     retcode = call(["ls", "-l"])
    322     """
--> 323     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
    324         try:
    325             return p.wait(timeout=timeout)

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    773                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    774                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 775                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    776         except:
    777             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1176                                          env,
   1177                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
-> 1178                                          startupinfo)
   1179             finally:
   1180                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

How to solve the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it using pydot library

```
import pydot

(graph,) = pydot.graph_from_dot_file('tree_real_data.dot')
graph.write_png('somefile.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

use check_call

```
tree.export_graphviz(model_name,'m1_ent.dot',filled=True,feature_names=features,
                     class_names= classes)

#convert dot into image
check_call(['dot','-Tpng','m1_ent.dot','-0','m1_ent.png'])
```